# Is it possible to dynamically add rules to 'localrules:'?

Tags: snakemake

The example of `localrules:` given here
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules
shows how to explicitly list rules that should be executed on the host node.

Is there a way to add rules at runtime, conditioning them on parameters of the workflow?

e.g. something that would look like the following?

```py
my_local_rules = ['rule1', 'rule_2']
if condition:
    my_local_rules.append('rule3')

localrules: my_local_rules
```

I've tried the following, which runs with a warning, indicating that the `localrules` directive is not doing what I'd like.

```py
local_rules_list = ['all']

if True:
   local_rules_list.append('test')

localrules: local_rules_list

rule all:
    input:
        # The first rule should define the default target files
        # Subsequent target rules can be specified below. They should start with all_*.
        "results/test.out"


rule test:
    input:
        "workflow/Snakefile"
    output:
        "results/test.out"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

Specifically, it fails with the following error:

```
localrules directive specifies rules that are not present in the Snakefile:
    local_rules_list
```

My specific use case is the software [Cell Ranger](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/what-is-cell-ranger) which has both a local mode and a [cluster mode](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/advanced/cluster-mode).

In local mode, the `cellranger` command is submitted as a job on a compute node.
In cluster mode, the `cellranger` command should run on the head node, as `cellranger` itself handles the job submission to the compute nodes.

I would like my workflow to let users choose which mode to run Cell Ranger (e.g. `local` or `sge`) and as a result, if `mode: sge` the workflow would add the rule that runs `cellranger` to `localrules: ...`.
Is that possible, or can local rules only be hard coded in the Snakefile?

Best,
Kevin

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. I'll try now and report back to confirm when I got it to work. Sorry for the duplicated question, the title of that other questions is a bit confusing and I didn't spot it during my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

The 'hack' suggested in the [post linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972358/snakemake-list-rules-to-execute-in-cluster-and-local) in @Maarten-vd-Sande's comment works fine for me.

I have adapted the suggested hack as follows, in this toy example.
Namely:

- rule `all` is explicitly set in the `localrules` directive
- rule `test1` is added to the set of local rules using the hack, demonstrating the use of a dummy condition, as I illustrated in my question
- rule `test2` is here as a negative control that is not added to list of local rules at any point

```py
# The main entry point of your workflow.
# After configuring, running snakemake -n in a clone of this repository should successfully execute a dry-run of the workflow.


report: "report/workflow.rst"

# Allow users to fix the underlying OS via singularity.
singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3"

localrules: all

rule all:
    input:
        # The first rule should define the default target files
        # Subsequent target rules can be specified below. They should start with all_*.
        "results/test1.out",
        "results/test2.out"


rule test1:
    input:
        "workflow/Snakefile"
    output:
        "results/test1.out"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"

      
rule test2:
    input:
        "workflow/Snakefile"
    output:
        "results/test2.out"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"


include: "rules/common.smk"
include: "rules/other.smk"


# Conditionally add rules to the directive 'localrules'
_localrules = list(workflow._localrules) # get the local rules so far

if True: # set condition here
    _localrules.append('test1') # add rules as required

workflow._localrules = set(_localrules) # set the updated local rules
```

Thanks!